# Getting error on kubectl get nodes command

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, kubectl

I am getting an error while running the following command. I have updated gcloud SDK but still facing same error.

```
kubectl get nodes


Unable to connect to the server: error executing access token command "/Users/salayhin/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud config config-helper --format=json": err=exit status 1 output= stderr=Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/salayhin/google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py", line 95, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/salayhin/google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py", line 54, in main
    from googlecloudsdk.core.util import encoding
  File "/Users/salayhin/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.util import lazy_regex
  File "/Users/salayhin/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/lazy_regex.py", line 25, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.util import lazy_regex_patterns
ImportError: cannot import name lazy_regex_patterns
```

Comment: unfortunately i think this issue is from the Python client libraries, not from the Google Cloud SDK.

Comment: Could you please provide what kind of linux system you have google cloud SDK installed on?

Comment: @MdSirajusSalayhin could you please mark the answer as approved if it helped solving the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it's just an error from the Google Cloud SDK happening [here](https://github.com/google-cloud-sdk/google-cloud-sdk/blob/master/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/lazy_regex.py#L25) indicating that you are probably missing [this file](https://github.com/google-cloud-sdk/google-cloud-sdk/blob/master/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/lazy_regex_patterns.py) on the same directory.

I would recommend re-install the [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) on whatever system you are using.